# Custom registry is not retrieved in block magento2

Tags: magento2, blocks, registry

I am setting custom registry in my module like below.

here is my controller file code.

```
use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface;

class Childcategory extends Action
{
protected $categoryRepository;
protected $resultJsonFactory;
protected $_coreSession;
protected $_coreRegistry = null;

public function __construct(
        Context $context, 
        CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository, 
        JsonFactory $jsonFactory,
        SessionManagerInterface $coreSession,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry
        )
{
    $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
    $this->resultJsonFactory = $jsonFactory;
    $this->_coreSession = $coreSession;
    $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
    $parentId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('category_id');  
    $this->_coreRegistry->register('category_parent_id', $parentId);
    $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($parentId);
    $childrenData = [];
    return $this->resultJsonFactory->create()->setData($childrenData);
 }


  }
```

Block file code.

```
 class Category extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template{
protected $categoryFactory; 
protected $_storeManager;    
protected $_categoryCollectionFactory;
protected $_coreRegistry;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry
)
{    
    $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->_categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
    $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function getCatId()
{
    $sessionId = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('category_parent_id');      
    if(isset($sessionId) && $sessionId != ''){
        return $sessionId;
    }else{
        return;
    }
    }
 }
```

If i try to access the registry value in my template file like below.

```
$registryId = $block->getCatId();
```

I am not getting the value, but i have set it in my controller.

Where i am doing wrong, can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using for controller output.

```
return $this->resultJsonFactory->create()->setData($childrenData);
```

there is no block call in this controller, so you can't get value of registry in your block. You have to render your layout or call your block directly controller.

Comment: you mean i have not defined block class for this controller?

Comment: @jafarpinjar yes

Answer (score 0):

Change the block code like this .

```
class Category extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
   protected $categoryFactory; 
   protected $_storeManager;    
   protected $_categoryCollectionFactory;
   protected $_coreRegistry;

   public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry)
{    
    $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->_categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
    $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function getCatId()
{
    $sessionId = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('category_parent_id');      
    if(isset($sessionId) && $sessionId != '')
    {
        return $sessionId;
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: hi @Dhiren, where is mistake? seems the code is same

Comment: protected $_coreRegistry; no need to set null there.

Comment: yes @Dhiren, used this code, still i am not getting value, cleared the cache also

Comment: I can get value in controller, but from block file, its not returning value.

Comment: Have you tried this? Is it working for you @Dhiren?

Comment: hi Dhiren, can you please check once from your end?